# I'm trying to run 3 .cmd files from 3 different locations at a time

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to run 3 .cmd files from 3 different locations at a time. I have tried with SQL Job agent and windows task scheduler. It is not recognising the path of the folder and batch did not trigger.

I tried to execute thru .bat file and not succeeded.

My path is :

```
J:\TXT_RP\5500\Batch\Cmd\Batch_Exec\Execute_RunCheckImportBatch_10115.cmd 

J:\TXT_RP\5600\Batch\Cmd\Batch_Exec\Execute_RunCheckImportBatch_10115.cmd

J:\TXT_RP\5700\Batch\Cmd\Batch_Exec\Execute_RunCheckImportBatch_10115.cmd
```

So , I want to execute these 3 cmd files at a time .

Could someone help me with this ?

Answer (score 0):

Place in a batch file

```
start "" cmd /c "J:\TXT_RP\5500\Batch\Cmd\Batch_Exec\Execute_RunCheckImportBatch_10115.cmd"
start "" cmd /c "J:\TXT_RP\5600\Batch\Cmd\Batch_Exec\Execute_RunCheckImportBatch_10115.cmd"
start "" cmd /c "J:\TXT_RP\5700\Batch\Cmd\Batch_Exec\Execute_RunCheckImportBatch_10115.cmd"
```

and call this batch file.